# How is no of views determined?

Tags: discussion, questions

For every question, there is a number of views.

What does it mean ? How many times a question has been viewed/opened ? How many times it has been opened by a unique member of community ? Or something else ?

How is it determined ? Is a log of IP addresses visiting the question kept ? If it is, who all can access it ? If not, then how is it determined ?

Comment: Yeah, it's based on IP addresses (a rough counter [to calculate the popularity of a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188348/205334), but timed with some intervals, I guess). It's obvious that the site-devs can access almost anything (It's their site!!!). BTW, I won't assume anything on the mod-powers, as they've always made me wonder :D

Comment: @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut why don't you post your comment as an answer, I think there is no more to say!

Comment: @user689: Nah, if I had been sure about what I just said, I'd have posted it as an answer already. I thought someone would post a better answer :)

Comment: @Waffle'sCrazyPeanut Really, that should be an answer. By the way, moderators do not have access to IP address information on a question. We can get access to some information about what IP addresses a given _user_ has logged in from, but that's all.

Comment: @ David Z: wow ! So you people can spy on everyone ?

Comment: I tried this and in my browser, every time I hit refresh, the counter increases by one. I have heard 'Cookies" can be used to record unique page views and can be more reliable.But it will a huge problem if we have to accept a cookie for every question we visit.Maybe recording the number of page hits as per user ids is a way out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, the number of views is determined by the IP addresses of individual users, who had viewed the question in the past. It's just a [timed counter to measure roughly "how popular the question is"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188348/205334).

What I mean by "timed intervals" is that, say you view a question today. And, (let's say) after a week or so, you view it again. Refresh the page, and you'll find out that the views have increased by one.

While mods don't have any privy information regarding the views, it's really obvious that the site-developers can view almost anything. [Sklivvz](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66/sklivvz), and [Shog](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2911/shog9) are examples, as they visit us often (:P).

Comment: Just to clarify, there's no per-question log of users or IP addresses used to calculate question views (although that would be useful on occasion). There's a field that is incremented when someone views it (with some fairly strict sanity-checks in place to keep repeated views by a single person from skewing it). In practice, question views are probably under-counted in many instances.